# Delete one line on collection mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("554a4aee0faaf2a804b7acd9"), "text" : "bla;", "comment_name" : "test1", "comment_email" : "test@hotmail.fr", "article" : { "_id" : NumberLong(4) } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("554a4ba90faaf2a604b7acd9"), "text" : "hey", "comment_name" : "test2", "comment_email" : "tes2t@hotmail.fr", "article" : { "_id" : NumberLong(4) } }
```

I want to delete one line I have made:

```
> db.comments_4.( { "comment_name" : "test2" })
```

I have this error

> 2015-05-06T20:17:24.198+0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   (

Comment: Try `db.comments_4.remove({"comment_name" : "test2" })`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function name, "remove" in this case, after accessing comments_4 collection.

```
db.comments_4.remove({"comment_name" : "test2" })
```

Wish it helps!